# Convergence of sequence of power series implies convergence of coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose we are given that a sequence of functions $f_n(z)$ convergences pointwise to $f(z)$ on the interval $[0,1]$.  Suppose further that all of these functions are given by power series centered at 0 with radius of convergence $R > 1$.

To fix notation, say $f_n(z) = a_{n, 0} + a_{n, 1}z + a_{n, 2} z^2 + \dots$

and $f(z) = a_0  + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \dots$.

We are given $f_n(z) \to f(z)$ as $n \to \infty$, for each fixed $z \in [0,1]$.

Is it true that $a_{n, k} \to a_k$ as $n \to \infty$, for each $k$? Why?  We can't use complex analysis it seems, since we are only on $[0,1]$.

If not, is it true under the additional assumption that all the $a_{n, k}$ and $a_n$ are uniformly bounded by some $M$?

Answer (score 5):

No, this is false. Define $f_n(z) = \sin(nz)/n, n= 1,2,\dots$ Then $f_n(z) \to 0$ pointwise on $\mathbb R$ (in fact, uniformly on $\mathbb R.$) But $f_n'(0) = 1$ for all $n,$ while $f'(0) = 0.$

Comment: So under what conditions is it true?

Comment: Could it still be true if all of the coefficients are uniformly bounded?

Comment: I think if all coefficients are uniformly bounded, then the answer is yes, using a normal families argument (complex analysis).

Comment: @MarkViola Your two varibables for Moore-Osgood appear to be $n$ and $K,$ as in $k=0,1,\dots, K.$ So uniform convergence for $z\in [0,1]$ seems irrelevant. Furthermore, not even pointwise convergence with respect to $n$ has been established; in fact, this is the very question at hand.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, you're correct.  We needed that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k(n)z^k$ converges uniformly in $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for each $z$, and we needed piecewise convergence of the $C_k(n)$.  We have been given neither of those.  I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @zhw. In your example, $f_n(z)=\frac1n \sin(nz)$, which approaches $0$ only for $z\in \mathbb{R}$.  So, let's assume that $z\in \mathbb{R}$.  Then, does it not suffice to simply say that $f_n\to 0$ while $\lim_{n\to\infty }a_{n,k}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^kn^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\ne 0$? what is the point of discussing $f_n'(0)$?

Comment: @MarkViola  $f_n'(0)=a_{n,1}.$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, but it seems obfuscate the basic idea, which you have shown, that the $a_{n,k}$ don't approach the $a_k$ terms.  In fact, it is easy to see directly that none of the $a_{n,k}$ terms converge.

Comment: @MarkViola  Well yes, once you have the example, you can compute all day with it. But how do you find the example? I found it from the simple (not obfuscatory!) idea of finding a sequence $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, while $f_n'(0)$ does not converge to $0.$

Comment: @zhw. And that is fine.  But once you had the example, by however you found it, why not then "compute all day?"  ;-)) I'm not trying to be nit picky here, but rather suggest that it might be more instructive to mention directly that none of the  $a_{n,k}$ converges.  And (+1) for the solution.

Comment: @MarkViola  I had solved the problem, so I was off to the races. (btw: for half the $k$ we have all $a_{nk}=0.$)

Comment: Yes, the even terms are $0$.